# SVG background image - centered and scaled

Tags: svg, background-image

Basically I need to mimic CSS `background-image`, `background-repeat:no-repeat`, `background-position: 50% 50%` and `background-size: 90%` (with a little difference) to SVG shapes. It should look like this (the percent, shield and anchor as background images):

[image]

The requirements are:

- the image has to be used together with the `fill` color and be **independent** on it (`background-image`)
- it has to be only one image, not lots of copies (`background-repeat:no-repeat`)
- it must be centered within the shape (`background-position: 50% 50%`)
- the image must fit the shape and not exceed its borders
- ideally, there should be kind of a padding applied to the image (`background-size: 90%`)

I am not that skilled in SVG usage yet. Tried using `patterns` and playing with pattern units and aspect ratio:

```
<pattern id="p2" height=".9" width=".9" 
    patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
    patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
    viewBox="0 0 140 165" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
>
    <g width="1" height="1" transform="matrix(1.25,0,0,-1.25,0,164.4025)" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    ...
    </g>
</pattern>
```

This way the image is scaled to 90% of the shape size (pattern `width` and `height`), centered by means of `viewBox` tweaking (works only with this particular one). But repeated and in Firefox - stretched (as of v29), as if it was `preserveAspectRatio = none`. In Chrome there is no stretch. And I can't think of a way to use the image with fill color.

[The live example](http://jsfiddle.net/j3knq/1/)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** Answer corrected because I misunderstood the question.

To make your pattern do what you want (have a 10% padding), you should adjust the pattern's `viewBox` values.

So, for example, the non-padded viewBox for your anchor shape is:

```
viewBox="0 0 137 166"
```

You want to have a 10% padding, so let's add 17 around the edges. I chose 17 because it is approximately 10% of the height:

```
viewBox="-17 -17 171 200"
```

Here we have subtracted 17 from minX and minY and added 34 to the width and height.  So your new pattern definition looks like this:

```
<pattern id="p2" height="1" width="1"
         patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"
         patternContentUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
         viewBox="-17 -17 171 200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
    <g> ... </g>
</pattern>
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3knq/18/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that patterns are for, well, patterns (as the name says). But drawing three (altogether) pseudo-bg elements for each of many shapes seems quite excessive. So does js handling of just three predefined bgs. And patterns seem to aid here to some point, so I naturally wanted to know if there is a way to make them work do all the job.

Comment: The elements would be drawn either way, whether they were a pattern or not.  There doesn't have to be a separate "anchor" for each shape. It can be defined once and reused.

Comment: BigBadaboom, do you you mean to define a shape in `<defs>` or as a `<symbol>` and than `<use>` it? If so, (if I get it right) it will require to manually calculate the `<use>` element' position or create lots of them with predefined positions, which is the excessive part. `pattern` on the other hand could be applied as just an attribute `fill="#patten1"`, which was the thing that attracted me in using them.

Comment: I see now I misunderstood your question a bit.  I've rewritten my answer to achieve what I now believe you are after.

Comment: Sorry it took me that long to reply. It does work - just as planned, thank you for the time and advice! Yet, the patterns seem to be stretched to the form's edges - only in Firefox (as of v29 at least). Is it really a bug, or could all the other browsers (tested in Chrome, IE 10, Presto- and Blink-Opera) are doing this in a wrong way?

Comment: I just noticed your fiddle had `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid none"` which I didn't notice and copied across to my demo.  That is an invalid preserveAspectRatio value.  It might be the cause of the FF error.  I've corrected my answer and fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, I tried both `meet` and `none`, neither helps with FF.